# I'm trying to programmatically clear copy/paste bookmarks inserted as part of the conversion process into the editor

Tags: tinymce

**Problem**

Bookmark characters get pasted into the tinymce editor as part of the copy/paste conversion process from a Word doc into the tinymce editor.

**Docs**

These are the docs for the latest version (v6) of tinymce as of 08/17/2023:

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/copy-and-paste/

**Debug setup**

Created a stripped-down standalone version of a tinymce implementation isolate the issue as much as possible. ChatGPT recommended a solution using the paste_preprocess handler which I implemented here:

https://codepen.io/coder32123/pen/XWoWWXK

**Debug results**

The issue still occurs. The following code in paste_preprocess removes the spans with mso-bookmark:

```
var cleanedData = clipboardData.replace(/<span[^>]*mso-bookmark[^>]*>/g, '');
```

But then tinymce replaces those with “_Hlk” anchors in the markup.  You can select the [View > Source Code] menu item on the tinymce control to inspect the generated source code. The following subsequent code is written to remove the _Hlk anchors but tinymce writes out those anchors to the output source code anyway:

```
var cleanedData = clipboardData.replace(/<a[^>]*name='_Hlk[^>]*>/g, '');
```

Copying the same code to a paste_postprocess method has the same result as well.

**Next Steps**

TinyMCE advertises a “premium” PowerPaste plugin that provides improved paste support, including support for Microsoft Word, Microsoft Excel and Google Docs content. It also includes the option to clean or merge the styles when pasting content into the editor.  This is only available for paid TinyMCE subscriptions.

Is there a way to configure/implement what I'm trying to achieve with the free version of TinyMCE?  Otherwise, any idea if the premium PowerPaste plugin will allow me to achieve this goal?